# How can i load an image in to a template doc based on information submitted in to a sheet from a form?

Tags: google-apps-script

Basically what i am trying to accomplish is to create a contact and image card for each of my students. I have them fill in a survey which I created with Google forms. When that form is submitted an App Script grabs my doc template, fills in all of the information from the sheet to its correct place then creates a doc and a pdf and emails them to me. What I still need it to do is pull an image from a drive folder (Or other location if drive will be an issue and i have read in other posts) that is labeled with their student id's (ex. 588305.jpg) and insert it into the doc. They provide their student id's in the survey so it is available in the sheet t match. Attached are links to the sheet, template,and the code.

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IOqTqaeD_TVpbHm3D_VhzGMckEURGguL5WUC5II8Q0U/edit?usp=sharing)

[Template](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KuvJC68gRaZP_8mSj_evj8UaYLmYt0vu2eU44MBN3fA/edit?usp=sharing)

```
    var docTemplate = "1KuvJC68gRaZP_8mSj_evj8UaYLmYt0vu2eU44MBN3fA";
var docName = "Student Profile Template";
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var email1 = "sbrumbaugh@piperschools.us";
  var last = e.values[3];
  var first = e.values[4];
  var nick = e.values[5];
  var grade = e.values[17];
  var gender = e.values[10];
  var birthday = e.values[9];
  var student_email = e.values[6];
  var student_phone = e.values[7];
  var student_id = e.values[8];
  var w1 = e.values[32];
  var o1t = e.values[33];
  var w2 = e.values[34];
  var o2t = e.values[35];
  var w3 = e.values[36];
  var o3t = e.values[37];
  var w4 = e.values[38];
  var o4t = e.values[39];
  var p1 = e.values[24];
  var i1t = e.values[25];
  var p2 = e.values[26];
  var i2t = e.values[27];
  var p3 = e.values[28];
  var i3t = e.values[29];
  var p4 = e.values[30];
  var i4t = e.values[31];
  var seminar = e.values[23];
  var parent_first = e.values[13];
  var parent_last = e.values[14];
  var parent_phone = e.values[15];
  var parent_email = e.values[16];
  var win_user = e.values[40];
  var schoology_user = e.values[41];
  var schoology_pass = e.values[42];
  var autodesk_user = e.values[47];
  var autodesk_pass = e.values[48];

var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+last +', ' +first)
.getId();

var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  copyBody.replaceText('keyFirstName', first);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyLastName', last);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyNickName', nick);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyGradeLevel', grade);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyGender', gender);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyBirthDay', birthday);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyStudentEmail', student_email);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyCell', student_phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyW1', w1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyW2', w2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyW3', w3);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyW4', w4);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyO1t', o1t);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyO2t', o2t);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyO3t', o3t);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyO4t', o4t);  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyP1', p1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyP2', p2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyP3', p3);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyP4', p4);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyI1t', i1t);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyI2t', i2t);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyI3t', i3t);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyI4t', i4t);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySeminar', seminar);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyIDNumber', student_id);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPGfirst', parent_first);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPGlast', parent_last);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPGemail', parent_email);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPGphone', parent_phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyWin', win_user);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySchoologyUser', schoology_user);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySchoologyPass', schoology_pass);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAutodeskUser', autodesk_user);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAutodeskPass', autodesk_pass);


copyDoc.saveAndClose();

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

var subject = "Student Profile Template";
var body = "Student Profile Template for " + last +', ' +first + " " + "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + copyId;
MailApp.sendEmail(email1, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});  

DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(false); 


}
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Stephan

Comment: The data on the sheet is not actual names etc, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms don't support file upload. I found this script by Amit Agarwal that will do the work: http://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files

You will have to rewrite your google form to html, good luck !